# cant pipe SLURM `module list`command

Tags: pipe, io-redirection, slurm

I am working on a SLURM cluster and there is a command to list all loaded software modules. I want to process the output and i.e. grep it for a certain word. However if I try to use the pipe I get unexpected output which I don't understand.

```bsh
$ module list

Currently Loaded Modules:
  1) miniconda3-4.8.2-gcc-8.3.1-altn3cq

$ which module
module ()
{ 
    eval $($LMOD_CMD bash "$@") && eval $(${LMOD_SETTARG_CMD:-:} -s sh)
}

$ module list | wc -l

Currently Loaded Modules:
  1) miniconda3-4.8.2-gcc-8.3.1-altn3cq



0

$ module list | grep conda

Currently Loaded Modules:
  1) miniconda3-4.8.2-gcc-8.3.1-altn3cq
```

Thus I am wondering why I can't pipe the output of `module list`

Comment: Probably the command send the result to STDERR. Try this: `module list 2>&1| wc -l`

Comment: Ah indeed you were correct! I redirected stderr and stdout to seperate files as shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/692407/5105118 and only stderr contained the output. Thank you for the help! Do you want to write an answer so that I can upvote it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like the command send the output to STDERR instead of STDIN. And because the terminal display both of them you get the things on this way. To send STDERR to STDIN and be able to filter the command output you can use this way:

```
module list 2>&1 | grep conda
```